# How to obtain PID of executed program?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm going to execute a command, which is not run in the background, and I want it's pid. Is there a direct way to obtain the pid?

I could do:

```
command &
PID="$!"
wait "$PID"
```

But it doesn´t seem very elegant.

Comment: Why do you think it's not elegant ? Using `$!` is the proper way to handle PIDs in this case. You don't really need the temporary variable though (you can directly type `wait $!`), but that's about it

Comment: @Aserre Hadn't noticed that wait doesn't overwrite $! (since it isn't run on the background), so I could just do `command &; wait` and then I can store "$!" to do stuff with it. `command &; fg`should be equivalent as well.

Comment: If the process is not going to be run in the background, what possible uees could there be for knowing its PID once it has finished?

Comment: @tripleee Well, it's run in the background as `{stuff; command; more stuff;} &`. I wanted to wait until `command` had finished, not the whole block. But I'm going to create a temporal directory when it finishes and just loop checking if the directory is created or not.

Comment: So `(stuff; pid=$(sh -c 'echo $$; exec command'); more stuff) &`?

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
pgrep <service_name/command_name>
```

Since you are leaving the command run in the background with the ampersand `&`.

As Die covers this in their man page, it is where I always check for help on the subject Die [pgrep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep)

> pgrep looks through the currently running processes and lists the process IDs which matches the selection criteria to stdout. All the criteria have to match.

You can output that to a variable as you are doing.
I just dunno if this is what you are looking for in the first approach cause this can return more than one PID.

But `$!` is as elegant, or more, as any other command, especially in this case.
You have to think that if it is efficient than it is all that matters.

You can also do something more wild. But this is a bit too much for w/e reason.

```
ps ax | grep "<service_name" | tr -s " " ":" | cut -f 2 -d ":"
```